# Quicksort for first k elements only

Tags: java, quicksort

I am trying out quick sort with the case where I want to sort only `k` elements from an array of `n` elements. I wrote this code, which works fine for all n elements and I get the input array sorted, but I am not able to get just the first k elements sorted, and I am not able to figure out the mistake, can someone help?

If I remove confitions `if (partitionIndex > k )`  and `else if (partitionIndex < k)` it works fine for all n elements. How do I add logic to only work for k elements?

Eg.

```
int[] input = {8, 4, 1, 3, 7, 5};
int k = 2;

int[] expectedOutput = {1, 3};
```

So per my code below, I am partitioning the array as happens in quick sort, where all elements before the partition index are smaller or equal, and after are larger.
So in the above ideal example, after the first pass, the array would be

```
{4, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8} parititionIndex = 3
```

So here, `partitionIndex > k`, so I can only deal with the first half, and not worry about the second half. But my code does not seems to be working, and I cannot figure out why.

```
void quickSort(int[] array, int k) {
    int start = 0; 
    int end = array.length - 1; 
    quickSort(array, start, end, k);
}

void quickSort(int[] array, int start, int end, int k) {
    if (start >= end) {
        return;
    }

    int partitionIndex = partition(array, start, end);
    if (partitionIndex > k ) {
        quickSort(array, start, partitionIndex - 1, k);
    } else if (partitionIndex <= k) {
        quickSort(array, start, k - 1, k);
    }
}

int partition(int[] array, int start, int end) {
    int pivot = array[end];
    int i = start;

    for (int j = start; j < end; j++) {
        if (array[j] <= pivot) {
            swap(i, j, array);
            i++;
        }
    }

    swap(i, end, array);

    return i;
}

void swap(int x, int y, int[] array) {
    if (x != y) { // else xor produces 0
        array[x] = array[x] ^ array[y];
        array[y] = array[x] ^ array[y];
        array[x] = array[x] ^ array[y];
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an overload with the indices parameter `start` and `end`. What is the problem in using these? If you want to sort the first 10 numbers of a bigger array you could use `start=0` and `end=9`.

Comment: Why do you need `end` and `k`? I suppose, you need only `end` (which equals to `k`). And swap elements only inside this left part of the array. The right part will stay unchanged.

Comment: No, I mean, if I have an array of 10 integers, and I want to retrieve the first 4 of the sorted array, then I want to avoid with the rest of the array based on partition. Eg. If partition is 5 in this case, then I can avoid sorting the second half of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for your example `{8, 4, 1, 3, 7, 5} and k = 2;`
Consider this array `{8, 4, 3, 7, 5 , 1}`
after the first pass, the array would be

```
{ 1, 4, 3, 7, 5, 8} parititionIndex = 0
```

after the second pass, the array would be

```
{ 1, 4, 3, 7, 5, 8} parititionIndex = 1
```

And will remain the same on further passes.

You can alternatively try finding the first k smallest elements in the array using modified quick sort. In such a version we would sort only one half of the array depending on the position of the parititionIndex. Once we have the k smallest elements we can further sort these using quick sort again.

P.S: Probably not the most efficient way to do this, but a solution to your question.